# MDX crossjoin with 5 dimensions

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, cross-join

Assuming we have the following dimension

- DATE
- CONTRACTOR
- COLOR
- SIZE

and a set of 6 measures, we want to get the 6 measures for every Semestrer, Trimester, Month, Contractor, Color and Size for a given Year.

Here is my MDX query:

```
SELECT 
   { 
         ... the 6 measures ... 
   } ON COLUMNS, 
    { 
          (
                [Dim DATE].[year].[year].AllMembers * 
                [Dim DATE].[SEMESTRE NOM].[SEMESTRE NOM].AllMembers * 
                [Dim DATE].[TRIMESTRE NOM].[TRIMESTRE NOM].AllMembers * 
                [Dim DATE].[MOIS NOM].[MOIS NOM].AllMembers *
                [Dim CONTRACTOR].[Name CONTRACTOR].AllMembers *
                [Dim COLOR].[Name COLOR].AllMembers *
                [Dim SIZE].[Name SIZE].AllMembers 
         ) 
   } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 

 FROM   ( 
   SELECT ( { StrToSet( "[Dim DATE].[year].[year].&[" + @Year + "]" , CONSTRAINED ) }      

   ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [TheCube]
```

This is very slow (more than 20 minutes), with only 6 Contractors, 6 Color, 18 sizes... and what is the differences between `.AllMembers` and `.Members` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the actual number of years in your hierarchy, you might create a quite large set with the crossjoin. As icCube mentionned in the comment, why not using :

```
StrToSet( "[Dim DATE].[year].[year].&[" + @Year + "]" , CONSTRAINED )
```

in the crossjoin on the ROWS ?

AllMembers vs Members; here is a [doc](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/AllMembers.html); allmembers include the calc. members; do you have any costly calc. members ?

How many members do you have in [Dim DATE].[MOIS NOM].[MOIS NOM].AllMembers ? trimestre, semestre ?

Comment: Thanks! 50 years, 2 semestres for each, 4 trimestres for each year, 12 months for each year